How can i enable kafka metrics in Kafka streams spring boot app
Prometheus end point is working but not getting kafka metrics in that
I added the micrometer-prometheus dependency and spring.jmx.enabled: true and management configuration is needed
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micrometer/micrometer-registry-prometheus -->
 <dependency>     
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>     
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>    
    <version>1.12.5</version> 
 </dependency>

I tried adding the KafkaStreamsMetrics but getting null pointer when trying to get the streams from streams builder bean.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

StreamsBuilderFactoryBean can return the KafkaStreams once the streams state changes to Created, here  is the sample to set KafkaStreamsMetrics using a state listener.
   streamsBuilderFactoryBean.setStateListener((newState, oldState) - > {
       if (oldState.name().equals(KafkaStreams.State.CREATED.name())) {
           new KafkaStreamsMetrics(streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams()).bindTo(meterRegistry);
       }
   })

